# Why first click anywhere in empty space in document initiate the code instead of clicking on hyperlink and why too many tabs open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have list of RSS feed (rss page) in mobile app. I want to open each feed link once clicked, in different tab (in Android) and in iOS want to open _blank. Below code works fine for me.

**First issue** is I need to click once in empty place on rss page, then it works; otherwise app replaced itself with the external hyperlink webpage.

**Second issue** as many times I click anywhere in rss page or rss links; on next rss click it opens that many tabs. (e.g I click 3 times in empty space in page and already 2 times visit rss links; on next hyberlink click, it tries to open 5 tabs).

index.html

```
<script>
$(document).click(function(e){
    $('a').click(function(){
        var myurl= $(this).attr('href');
        if(myurl.indexOf('/') > -1)
        {
            //alert('linked found');
            if (typeof navigator !== "undefined" && navigator.app) 
            {
                navigator.app.loadUrl(myurl, {openExternal: true});
            } 
            else 
            {   
                window.open(myurl, "_blank");
            }   
            myurl='';
            return false;
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#btnnewgrant").click(rssfeedbtn);
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="rssfeed">
    <div data-role="header"> 
        <h1>Grants New Opportunity List by Agency</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <div class="myfeedheading">Grants New Opportunity </div>
        <div id="busy1" style="color:#000000"><img src="ajaxloader.gif"></img>
    </div>

    <div id="myfeeddiva" class="myfeed"></div>
    </div>
<div>
```

feed.js

```
function rssfeedbtn()
{
    $('#myfeeddiva').empty();
    $.mobile.changePage("#rssfeed", {reverse:false, transition:"slide"});
    var rssurl='http://www.ddd.ddd/rss/asdd.xml';
    $.get(rssurl, function(data) {
        var $xml = $(data);
        var mytext="";
        $xml.find("item").each(function() {
            mytext+='<a href="';
            mytext+=$(this).find("link").text();
            mytext+='">';
            mytext+=$(this).find("title").text();
            mytext+='</a>';
            mytext+='<br>';
            mytext+=$(this).find("pubDate").text();
            mytext+='<br>';
            mytext+='<br>';
        }); 
        $('#busy1').hide();
        $('#myfeeddiva').append(mytext);
    });     
}
```

Comment: @mpalencia, do you have any suggestion regarding my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attach click event handler in another click handler attached to the document. So when you click anywhere then a handler is attached to your links. You can have any number of handlers so if you click 10 times anywhere then there will be 10 handlers on your links and code will run 10 times on click on a link.

You need to change

```
$(document).click(function(e){
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

or shorter

```
$(function(){
```

---

Edit: If your links are created dynamically then you need to use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of .click.

Instead of:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
```

use

```
$('body').on('click','a',function (e) {
```

Comment: thank you for your input. If I change as you suggested, then links doesn't open in new tab.

Comment: What I am trying to do is; in dynmically popluated page, if someone click on any external link , it must open in new tab etc.